# ajax call working in browser but not in emulater

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

> i am making a phone gap application .in a html file i need a ajax
>   call,its working well in browser and showing me all results but
>   whenever i access my application in emu later ajax calls error
>   function rather of success function.i don`t know why its happening

what i have already tried is-:
 i have added $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; line 
i have replaced theme and jquery files .
i configured a new project as phonegap project and copy paste file into this ,but still same problem is coming

i am facing problem from few days ,no solutions found,please help me,i am stuck.

```
$
            .ajax({
                url : ' http://app.mydomainname.com/takeaway/find',
                data : {
                    location : "/takeaway/find/home-delivery-in-"
                            + $("#indexsearch").val()
                },
                type : 'POST',
                dataType : 'json',
                crossDomain : true,

                success : function searchSuccess(data, status) {
                    alert("sdfs");
                    $("#list").empty();
                    $
                            .each(
                                    data,
                                    function(i, item) {

                                        content = '<li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="false" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="portfolio-item ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-li-has-alt ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child ui-btn-up-c ui-corner-none">'
                                                + data[i].name
                                                + ' <a href="#" onclick="getdata('
                                                + data[i].id
                                                + ');" <h6 class="ui-li-heading">'
                                                + data[i].phone_no
                                                + '</h6><p</a></div></div>';
                                        $(content).appendTo("#list");
                                    });

                },
                error : function searchError(data, error) {
                    alert("in error", error);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Can you post your ajax code and config.xml so we can help you

Comment: have you given internet permission?

Comment: also check whether your emulator is connect with internet or not, for checking open normal browser and open any web page like google also check for any proxy is blocking or not...

Comment: @piyush i am unable to add config.xml,when i add here it shows some error

Comment: @rahul,i don`t understand how to add internet permission with it .

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> add this line in your manifest file

Comment: @rahul,problem solved,you are genius man,thanks alot. thanks very much,u saved my job :)

Comment: if this solves your problem then please accept my answer below. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` 
add this line in your manifest file

Comment: thanks again boss, call 7503435870 .if you need help from me  in future